# get current date with PHP help

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any script to check the current date in PHP?

I want to use this function to display a date from mysql db, and if the date from the db is the same as todays date, then display "TODAY" instead...

Thanks...

Comment: 18 questions, 1 accepted. Quit wasting our time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the current timestamp (seconds since 1970), use `time()`

To convert that into pretty much any format you want, use [`date()`](http://php.net/date)

To compare, there's a number of ways you could do it, but I think the simplest would be this:

```
$dateFromDB = getTheDateFromMyDB();   // "2009-10-20"
$today = date("Y-m-d");

if ($today == $dateFromDB) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about using the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function

Answer (score 0):

run a SQL query something like:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE entryDate = "'.date('m/d/Y').'";';
```

You will then be checking for todays date, get more info on the date() fn here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd point out that MySQL has a function for this:

```
select curdate() as todays_date
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("select CURDATE()");

$mysqlDate = mysql_result($result, 0);
```

The above will give you the date in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format, then you need to get the date from PHP.

```
$phpDate = date("Y-m-d");
```

This gives the same format as above.

You can then do something like this

```
if ( $phpDate == $mysqlDate )
      $dateToDisplay = 'Today';
else
    $dateToDisplay = $mysqlDate;

echo $dateToDisplay;
```

This assumes of course that the date.timezone has been set in the ini file or you can call

[date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to avoid warnings in Strict mode.